# Add twitter bootstrap scrollbar css to a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, scrollbar

I'm trying to use the css of the twitter bootstrap 3 for my vertical scrollbar. Which class should I use to call the css of the scrollbar? My div has a table inside it and I set the div to a certain height, then added the overflow function. But my scrollbar looks like my browser's scrollbar. How do I change it's appearance using twitter Bootstrap 3?

Comment: I am not sure that Bootstrap allows you to control the appearance of your browser's scrollbar. Can you clarify ?

Comment: There are plugins like jquery-slimscroll that allow you to change the appearance of the scrollbar of a div .. but nothing built into bootstrap https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll